# GraphQL standard for querying by various IDs

Tags: graphql

I have the following entities:

```
company
role
user
```

A company has many roles, and a role has many users.  I'm trying to build a GraphQL query which allows someone to query a company by the role Id.  My initial thought is to build a `companyByRoleId` query, but wanted to double check that this method is best practice.  In the example schema below, is `companyByRoleId` the best practice, or is there a better way to allow consumers to query the company that the role belongs to?

```
type Company {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  roles: Role[]
}

type Role {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  users: User[]
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}

query($roleId: ID!){
  companyByRoleId(roleId: $roleId){
    id
    name
  }
}

query($companyId: ID!){
  companyById(companyId: $companyId){
    id
    name
  }
}

query($userId: ID!){
  companyByUserId(userId: $userId){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: "to query the company that the role belongs to" suggests a Role is Company-specific.  Is that true, or can a Role have many Companies?

Comment: A role is company specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific queries along the lines of `companyByRoleId` and `companyByUserId` are arguably in the spirit of Graphql. Graphql is meant to be expressive and self-documenting.

Set against a combined generic alternative, say `companyById(roleID: String, userID: String)`, your design seems clearer and less error-prone.

Be that as it may, I believe there is a clearer, more explicit alternative to your current design.  Add a `Company` field to your `Role` and `User` types.  Consumers can access a user's or role's `Company` using your vanilla user and role queries.  You no longer need either `companyByRoleId` or `companyByUserId`.

```
type Role {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  users: User[]
  company: Company
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  company: Company
}

query($id: ID!){
  role(id: $id){
    id
    company {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

query($id: ID!){
  user(id: $id){
    id
    company {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The schema is set up to where `companyByRoleId` and the last query example you provided.  The reason why I thought about implementing `companyByRoleId` in order to remove the query nesting.  Because the end result of `companyByRoleId` and the "nested query" are similar, the method for getting there is very different.  For example, the actual "user to company" query would be user -> role -> company which is more verbose.  So there's really two use cases, just wanting to fetch a company by the user id, and fetching user and role and company information.

Comment: But the core question of "is the concept of companyByUserId not against GraphQL best practices" has been answered.  Thank you.